# What does "V.A." mean in datasheet dimensions?

Tags: datasheet, layout, footprint, dimensions

I'm looking at a datasheet for an LCD panel ([pdf link to datasheet](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/specs/NHD-12864MZ-FSW-GBW-L.pdf)).

I don't understand these two encircled dimensions:

[image: LCD dimensions]

What does the acronym "V.A." mean for these dimensions?

I have referenced a couple of other questions here on EE, but they don't cover this:
[Abstract Datasheet Dimension Notation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/154137/abstract-datasheet-dimension-notation)
[Reading dimension in datasheet](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/207844/reading-dimension-in-datasheet)

Comment: Many times those initials are "lefovers" from Chinese-English (or whichever languages) translation & don't make any sense in english. _HOWEVER_ those letters are in place of the error factor for their respective measurements, and could (conveniently) be initials for "Verified Absolute."

Comment: 6 years later, I'm using the exact same display with the exact same questions :D :D. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After looking into the linked LCD datasheet and answers here, I looked into other display products of the same company NEWHEAVENDISPLAY. And the interesting thing I found is apart from **V.A.** they use another therm called as **A.A.** Below is an example. Adding the [datasheet link](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/specs/NHD-14432WG-BTFH-VT.pdf) as well, if someone more interested can look into.

V.A. can be **V**iewing **A**rea or **V**iewing **A**ngle(if mentioned in degrees)

A.A. is **A**ctive **A**rea also called as effective area which the area for active pixels or icons or segments or patterns.

These links say all the same [link1](http://www.densitron.com/displays/lcd_glossary.aspx), [link2](http://www.ukai.com/documentos/00164-LNK00625.pdf) and [link3](http://www.pacificdisplay.com/lcd_glossary.htm).
[image]

Just hope ambiguity stops here.

Answer (score 9):

This is **not** a standard dimensioning abbreviation according to any standard I'm familiar with.

Instead, I suggest the (in 20:20 hindsight, obvious) meaning that the dimensions given refer to the nominal size of the LCD **V**iewing **A**rea.

Answer (score 1):

It looks a bit bigger than the 128*64 dots region. Inspired by @Spehro's answer I'm suggesting **V**iewing **A**perture.

I'm only playing with words. :^) It's the size of the hole you have to cut.

Answer (score 0):

From past experience with similar displays I would go with "Very Approximate".